# Questions about empty elements in arrays of Java

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone explain how to make empty elements in arrays of Java?
I was solving a problem about graph. The graph is given as follows: graph[i] is a list of all nodes you can visit from node i (i.e., there is a directed edge from node i to node graph[i][j]).

Example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqhbP.png)

```
input: Input: graph = [[1,2],[3],[3],[]]
```

I think the array in the example should be at least int[4][2]. So in the input, what is `graph[1][1]` or `graph[2][1]` or even `graph[3][1]`? Will the empty elements be just 0 or null?